# How to show that the following property is true?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $p_1^*(a)=\sup\{-b^Tz_1| A^Tz_1+a=0, z_1\succcurlyeq 0\}>\gamma$ then how to show that this is equivalent to $A^Tz_1+a=0, z_1\succcurlyeq 0, b^Tz_1 < \gamma$. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. $A,a, b, \gamma$ are constants in these expressions and $z_1$ is variable. (I found this in the solution manual of Convex optimization (by Boyd and Vandenberghe) book problem 5.18).

Comment: the inequality holds if and only if there is a $z_1$ for which the inequality holds

Comment: @LinAlg thanks for your comment. Which inequality you are referring to? Can you please explain in detail with some more detailed reasoning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LinAlg suppose there is a set (consisting of $\{z_1^1,z_1^2,z_1^3\}$) of $z_1$'s which satisfy $A^Tz_1+a=0,z \geq 0$. Further assume that $z_1^3$ maximizes $-b^Tz_1$ then $p_1^*(a)>\gamma$ translates to $-b^Tz_1^3>\gamma$. I do not understand how $-b^Tz_1^3>\gamma$ translates to $b^Tz_1^3<\gamma$. Maybe its a plain stupid question but I can not understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution manual has an error. If
$$\begin{pmatrix}A \\ a^T\end{pmatrix}x \leq \begin{pmatrix}b \\ \gamma\end{pmatrix}$$
has a solution, then Farkas lemma ([third variant on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma#Variants)) states that:
$$A^Tz_1+aw_1=0, b^Tz_1+\gamma w_1<0, z_1\geq 0, w_1\geq 0$$
has no solution. Note the + in front of $\gamma$, which explains the difference in sign.

Comment: thanks a lot for you help. sorry for being late.